# Passing values with appropriate types

Tags: scala, spray-json

I am new to scala. I have one parameter which can be either string, boolean or number. I don't know before which data type will come. Earlier for number I had following code.

```
Try {
        JsNumber(parameter._x.trim())
      } match {
        case Success(success) => myMethod(JsNumber(parameter._x.trim()))
        case Failure(ex) => myMethod(JsString(parameter._x.trim())
    }
```

If incoming parameter value is number then on success `JsNumber` is passed to method otherwise `JsString`. Now I can also have `Boolean` and `String` as incoming type as value. How can I write a generic code to do this so that appropriate value with appropriate type is passed to method?

Comment: What is `parameter`? What is `JsNumber`?

Comment: parameter is something I recieved after I have spliited my string and it is a second part of splitted string. JsNumber is available in spray json to convert string into Number

Comment: Please don't vandalize your post - it just makes more work for other people.

Answer (score 2):

reverse-engineering what I think your API is, I would guess it works with the following:

```
val paramString = parameter._2.trim
val asJval = Try(JsNumber(paramString))
  .orElse(Try(JsBoolean(paramString)))
  .getOrElse(JsString(paramString))
asJval.map(myMethod)
```

mind you, I don't know the type of `parameter`, `myMethod`, nor the signature of `JsNumber.apply` or if `JsNumber.apply` or whether `JsBoolean.apply` even exists: I'm just guessing at what it probably is based on common patterns.

Comment: how I should place this code  in the code I mentioned in my post

Comment: @Zulia What is this `myMethod` in your code ? If you use the code given above to create another variable `val jsonTry`. Then you can replace your given code by `jsonTry.map(myMethod)`

Comment: myMethod is my method in code which contains three argrs def myMethod(param1, param2, param3) where param 1 and 3 will always be string so I don't have problem in them but param 2 can string or boolean or number as I mentioned in my problem. so I need to ditact type of param2 at runtime and pass it in myMthod

Comment: could you please accomodate  your code in the method which I mentioned in my above comment?

Comment: So, your problem is `myMethod` and not `parameters._x`, and this whole `JsString, etc` thing is just to solve this `myMethod` use case ?

Comment: Using the above answer, You can just call `jsonTry.map(json => myMethod(parameter._1, json, parameter._3))`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to support only primitives, you can have the following:

```
def convertToJsValue(element: Any): JsValue = element match {
  case s: String => JsString(s)
  case number: Int => JsNumber(number)
  case b: Boolean => JsBoolean(b)
  case arr: Seq[Any] => JsArray(arr.map(convertToJsValue))
  case map: Map[String, Any] => JsObject(map.mapValues(convertToJsValue))
  case other => throw new UnsupportedOperationException(s"Type ${other.getClass.getName} is not supported.")
}
```

When having the following calls:

```
println(Json.stringify(convertToJsValue("aa")))
println(Json.stringify(convertToJsValue(55)))
println(Json.stringify(convertToJsValue(true)))
println(Json.stringify(convertToJsValue(Seq(0, 1, "aa", true))))
println(Json.stringify(convertToJsValue(Map("IntKey" -> 1, "StringKey" -> "aa", "BooleanKey" -> true))))

case class A(x: Int)
```

The output is:

```
"aa"
55
true
[0,1,"aa",true]
{"IntKey":1,"StringKey":"aa","BooleanKey":true}
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Type HelloWorld1$A is not supported.
```

Of course lists and arrays can be nested.

If you want to support case classes as well, you need to add an implicit format, such as:

```
object A {
  implicit val format: OFormat[A] = Json.format[A]
}
```

and add a case the the pattern matching:

```
case a: A => Json.toJson(a)
```

And the result of:

```
println(Json.stringify(convertToJsValue(A(10))))
```

will be:

```
{"x":10}
```

Comment: By the way, it is better not to throw exceptions in your workflow, as it has performance impact. https://www.baeldung.com/java-exceptions-performance

Comment: why you used map in your above case statmenet?

Comment: To cover all cases. You can remove it if you don't need it.

Comment: where I can call "convertToJsValue" in my above code I mentioned in queestion

Comment: you can do `Try(convertToJsValue(parameter._2.trim()))`

Comment: and where I can call myMethod?

Comment: @TomerShetah As per OP, they are getting parameter by splitting a `String`. So, their `element` is always going to be a `String` and never an `Int`.

Comment: @TomerShetah You proposed an edit, replacing tag `spray-json` with `play-json`. But OP mentions `spray-json` in comments, not `play-json`.

Comment: @sarvesheri, I state from the question: "I don't know before which data type will come"

Comment: @sarveshseri, `JsBoolean`, and `JsNumber` does not have any applyu methods with strings. So my answer will work on every case that the other one does.

Comment: @TomerShetah I don't think the purpose of these answers is to give more ways to commit the same (or even more) mistake ? Your code adds another layer of problem on top of already existing `JsX.apply` problem. Yes OP's code will not work but we are supposed to help in fixing that. You just need to consider that the input to that `convertToJsValue` is always going to be a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have understood, you are trying the Json thing just to solve your `myMethod` requirement.

Instead of looking into Json, you can create the ADT for your second parameter and use that.

```scala
trait SecondParameter

object SecondParameter {

  case class WrappedInt(value: Int) extends SecondParameter
  case class WrappedBoolean(value: Boolean) extends SecondParameter
  case class WrappedString(value: String) extends SecondParameter

  val intRegex = "[0-9]+".r

  def apply(string: String): SecondParameter =
    if (intRegex.matches(string))
      WrappedInt(string.toInt)
    else if (string.equals("true"))
      WrappedBoolean(true)
    else if (string.equals("false"))
      WrappedBoolean(false)
    else
      WrappedString(string)

}

def myMethod(first: String, second: SecondParameter, third: String): Unit = {
  second match {
    case SecondParameter.WrappedInt(i) => println(s"int :: $i")
    case SecondParameter.WrappedBoolean(b) => println(s"boolean :: $b")
    case SecondParameter.WrappedString(s) => println(s"string :: $s")
  }
}

myMethod(parameter._1, SecondParameter(parameter._2), parameter._3)
```